# How to implement UITabBarItems that pop out from the UITabBar?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to build a UITabBar with a UITabBarItem that pops out, just like the "Check In" tab item in Foursquare? (Screenshot below)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished by overlaying a `UIButton` on top of the 3rd tab bar item.

Here's a tutorial on how to accomplish it: http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/